# Laravel - Page not found- Routing error

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a file under , Views/approvals/approve.blade.php

Also have added it in the routes files as

Route::view('/approvals/approve','approvals.approve');

But when i go to the /home/approvals/approve url, There is an error message of page not found.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the route as /approvals/approve and you go to home/approvals/approve that's why try to visit

```
/approvals/approve
```

and it should work

Comment: can you provide some screenshots

Comment: Can you share your all routes, Probably request matched another routes, therefore error occurs.